# How to write a string using readkey inside a loop?

Tags: c#

I am making a program in which I need the user input to be invisible, and I read that `var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);` does just that.
To do what I need, however I need a string with multiple characters, so what I've done is

```
string Choice1=null;
User1Input:
while (true)
{
    var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        break;
    }
    Choice1 += key;
}
```

What is happening is that `key` simply doesn't read anything, because even if I press enter, the loop does not close.

Comment: Why can't you read the entire line `System.Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: I tried right now, it's underlined in red.Besides, I've read on this website somewhere that you can't make lines of input invisible, just single keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your sole intention is to hide the character while user types input in console. In that case you are in right track and your posted code looks good except the last line which says `Choice1 += key;`. It should be

```
Choice1 += key.KeyChar;
```

Your posted code with bit modification

```
string choice1=null; //casing of variable names
while (true)
{
    var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        break;

    choice1 += key.KeyChar;
 }
```